# Run other statements with the same PostgreSQL connection to use LISTEN

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with PHP+PDO to listen for notifications sent by PostgreSQL database.

I open the connection and first I run the SQL `LISTEN 'monitor_queue'` and then apply a PDO function that receives the notifications.

However, I need to execute other `SELECT` and `DELETE` queries for some tables involved.

Can I use the same connection that was used to perform the `LISTEN` or should I create a dedicated connection for the `SELECT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` operations that my code does?